# Connecting CloudTrail with OMS Log Analytics

Tags: azure, amazon-cloudtrail, azure-log-analytics, azure-gov

Has anyone imported AWS CloudTrail data into OMS Log Analytics before?  Since CloudTrail stores its data in S3 buckets, I would have to believe there is a way to do this.

Comment: This is a REAAAAALLY broad question. StackOverflow is best suited for more specific (ideally code-related) question, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

There are **many** ways to do this, ideally you'd pick one, give it a try and leverage StackOverflow for more specific technical questions.

You should start by exploring pushing your AWS CloudTrail data from S3 directly into Log Analytics via the [Log Analytics HTTP Data Collector API](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/log-analytics/log-analytics-data-collector-api).